# Getting the row indices of the first appearance of a list of values corresponding to a column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, indexing

I have a set of values as a numpy array. I want to find the row indices where the value in the numpy array first appear

```
data = {'name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'], 'year': [2012, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2014], 'reports': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
mid = np.array([2012,2013])
```

I want to find the row indices of the first appearances of the values 2012 and 2013 in the year column. My expected answer should be

> [0,2]

As a matter of fact row ids of any single appearance index will be ok with me. That is, I am ok with the answer

> [1,2]

also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is default index it is same like positions and all values are sorted use [`Series.searchsorted`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html):

```
idx = df['year'].searchsorted(mid).tolist()
print (idx)
[0, 2]
```

General solution with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for first values, last convert index to list:

```
idx = df[df['year'].isin(mid)].drop_duplicates('year').index.tolist()
print (idx)
[0, 2]
```

Comment: Though I use default row indexes, first approach did not work for me. Second one did work.